# I've placed a binary in my $PATH, but when I run it from powershell it gets its own directory instead of the current directory

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, path

I’ve installed [Hugo](http://gohugo.io) (a static website generator) on my Windows 7 system by placing it in a directory in my $PATH. When I try to run it, regardless of the directory I’m in, it's run in its own directory.

So if Hugo is located in `C:/users/me/utilities` and I'm in `C:/users/me/webstuff` in Powershell, running Hugo will cause it to look for files in `/me/utilities` instead of `/me/webstuff`. If I use `cmd` instead of `powershell`, it works fine.

It seems like this is an issue with Powershell, but Google/Stackoverflow/SuperUser aren't turning up any results. What am I not understanding?

Comment: What is the command were trying to execute?

Comment: Please run `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` from your work directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ([or was](https://github.com/spf13/viper/pull/20)) a [known issue](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/issues/560). As a workaround, append `-s .` to your command.

For instance, if your current working directory is where `config.toml` is located, use this:

```
PS D:\WWW\MySite> hugo new post/about.md -s .
```

If it's located in a different path...

```
PS C:\Users\Someuser> hugo new post/about.md -s "D:\WWW\MySite"
```

Comment: The issue has been fixed but the binary file hasn't been updated yet, it seems. You could fix this by [installing from source](https://github.com/spf13/hugo).

Comment: I originally had, but it was doing the same thing, which is why I tried the precompiled binary. Don't know why it didn't work then, maybe the fix isn't in the master branch yet. EDIT: Nope, it's clearly in the master branch. I'll give installing from source another try, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I honestly thought it was something to do with Powershell, not hugo itself. Looks like I was searching in the wrong place.

Comment: I tried installing from source again, but it's having the same problem. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: I haven't used Git a lot, but when you install from source, if it also fetches the code for [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper/), check whether `viper/viper.go` contains this line of code: `wd, _ := os.Getwd()`

Comment: It does contain that line of code. I think there's a further issue in hugo. I made a comment about it here: https://github.com/spf13/hugo/issues/604#issuecomment-64957422